# Stream mp4 file with watermark through a web using ffmpeg

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, ffserver

I'm having problems with *ffmpeg*, probably due to my inexperience with this software.

My basic need is the following: I have a series of videos with material that I want to protect so that it is not plagiarized. For this I want to add a watermark so that when a user views it, they also see some personal data that prevents them from downloading and sharing it without permission.

What I would like is to create a small Angular + Java application that does this task (invoking *ffmpeg* via `Runtime#exec`)

I have seen that from ffmpeg I can emit to a server, like [ffserver](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ffserver) but I wonder if there is a somewhat simpler way. Something like launching the *ffmpeg* command from my java application with the necessary configuration and having *ffmpeg* emit the video along with the watermark through some port/protocol.

**EDIT**

I have continued to investigate and I have seen that ffmpeg allows you to broadcast for WebRTC, but you need an adapter. What I would like and I don't know if it is possible is to launch ffmpeg so that it acts as a server and it can be consumed from the web.

Comment: _"...Invoking FFmpeg one way or another"_ That's called running an external process. Java has a **Process** API for that. Not sure what operating system you're using but try to read tutorials for it and run a simple app. Try running FFmpeg with some arguments (options) as a test like convert input JPG to output PNG or MP4. If working okay, then finally test telling FFmpeg to output video to a server location/port. Those are the steps to try and ask a question about...

Comment: My problem is not how to call ffmpeg from java, my problem is what arguments to pass to it to act as a server

Comment: FFmpeg cannot be used as a server. Your options are.. **(Option 1)** Make your own computer (IP) open to the internet, then FFmpeg can output to that same IP/port and outside listeners can see the video stream. You open by configuring your router, and forwarding one of its ports (same port as FFmpeg output). **(Option 2)** Just get webspace (that can run PHP) and put there a script that receives input data (video chunks) and stores them on server. FFmpeg can output to the url of server script, and listeners can connect to the stream via a second script that manages multi listener connects.

Comment: PS: **(Option 3)** Is to use FFserver. I think it does temporary port forwarding silently in the background... Further options include not using FFmpeg and instead use an encryption tool like WideVine, **..or...** Chrome/Edge browsers can decode/encode video frames (using their WebCodecs API) so you can modify pixels of input frames before outputting to connected user (via sockets or web server script).  **...or...**  Prepare the videos in such a way that frames can be replaced dynamically with a frame that has "user information" (_eg:_ every X mins your video cuts to a blue screen for 4 secs)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a Java example but we do something similar in our WebRTC .NET application. The code should be fairly straightforward to port to Java.

- FFMpeg parameters

  - Audio: https://github.com/liveswitch/liveswitch-connect/blob/486b35684e1e9be0df87937fe41e223a87a92219/src/FM.LiveSwitch.Connect/FFCapturer.cs#L151
  - Video: https://github.com/liveswitch/liveswitch-connect/blob/486b35684e1e9be0df87937fe41e223a87a92219/src/FM.LiveSwitch.Connect/FFCapturer.cs#L244
- RTP Reader (to process output from FFMpeg): https://github.com/liveswitch/liveswitch-connect/blob/master/src/FM.LiveSwitch.Connect/RtpReader.cs

The RTP packets received in the reader can be streamed over most Java WebRTC libraries.